# Projection problem - images not aligning (MODIS, Radarsat-2)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a MODIS image downloaded that is projected in EPSG3413 (NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North). I have another shapefile that is projected in EPSG 32617, WGS84 /UTM Zone 17N. They both seem to align well.

I have some SAR (radar) RADARSAT-2 images that I processed in SNAP toolbox. I project them with Ellipsoid-correction-> Average Height Range Doppler then choose a projection. I have tried a range of projections, including both of the above, but regardless, when I load them together in QGIS the R2 images are slightly offset from the MODIS image and the shapefile. I need to directly make comparison between pixels at the same location, so this is a significant problem.

In the example you can see the radar image and the same island from the MODIS offset. I'm struggling to figure out what the problem is. (this sea ice over ocean with a small island)

[image]

Comment: This seems to be not a projection problem, but one of two images not exactly aligned. Consider georeferencing at least one of the images, based on the other one.